# Is it possible to have a vertical MVC grid?

Tags: atk4

I have a MVCgrid with few fields with and expander to view all the detials.
Inside the expander, in order to view all the details I use an MVCform without submit action, but it feels weird.
Is it possible to have a MVCgrid vertical to show one single record, so I can see all the details, I mean like this:

```
+-------+-------+------+
| col1  | col2  |expand|
+-------+-------+------+
| data1 | data2 |[view]|
+-------+-------+------+
+-------+-------+
| col1  | data1 |
+-------+-------+
| col2  | data2 |
+-------+-------+
| col3  | data3 |
+-------+-------+
+-------+-------+------+
| data2 | data3 |[view]|
+-------+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, here you go:

```
$model=$this->add('Model_Alumno')->loadData($_GET['id']);

$data=array();
foreach($model->get() as $key=>$val){
    $row=array[];
    $row['label']=$model->getField($key)->caption();
    $row['val']=$val;
    $data[]=$row;
}
$g=$this->add('Grid');
$g->addColumn('text','label');
$g->addColumn('text','val');
$g->setStaticSource($data);
```

Comment: And where does $model comes from? when using a form I used $f=$this->add('MVCForm')->setModel('Alumno')->loadData($_GET['id']); How do I do it now?

Comment: I actually try that before, but I get an empty grid, ir I try to debug with var_dump($model), the page freez on loading...

Comment: you can't dump models like that, they have recursive links and var_dump is not smart enough to figure that out. If you enable XDebug, it replaces var_Dump with a more reasonable one.  Try to var_Dump($model->get()) or $data, but essentially what you are trying to do is to set Grid to use Static data.

Comment: Got it, we were missing one dimenssion in the array:     $x++;
            $data[$x]['label']=$model->getField($key)->caption();
            $data[$x]['val']=$val;

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I changed it to use temporary array, the code is cleaner.